# Writing an array with a range in Python3.x

Tags: python

Let's assume I want to write a row in a csv file.
This row will be something like:

```
name,last_name,birthday,hobby1,hobby2,hobby3, ... , hobby200
```

I can create an array like *['name', 'last_name' .... ]* but is there any possible way to set a range o

Comment: WDYM by "set a range"? Could you edit your question to include the outcome you'd expect?

Comment: This is the outcome I expect:

name,last_name,birthday,hobby1,hobby2,hobby3, ... , hobby200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not fully understand what you mean. But try this:

```
row = ['name','last_name','birthday']
for hobby_number in range(1, 201):
    row.append('hobby' + str(hobby_number))
print(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want this

```
List = ['name', 'last name', 'birthday']
List = List + ['hobby%d' %i for i in range(200)]
print(List)
```

output

```
['name', 'last name', 'birthday', 'hobby0', 'hobby1', 'hobby2', ....., 'hobby199']
```

if you don't want 0, and want 200 do `range(1, 201)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = 'name,last_name,birthday,' + ','.join(f'hobby{i}' for i in range(1, 201))
```

Instead, if you want a list:

```
result = ['name', 'last_name', 'birthday'] + [f'hobby{i}' for i in range(1, 201)]
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you're trying to convert:

```
['name', 'last_name' .... ]
```

into a string:

```
name,last_name,birthday,hobby1,hobby2,hobby3, ... , hobby200
```

Here's how you convert an array into a comma-separated string:

```
myList = ['name', 'last_name', 'birthday']
myString = ','.join(myList)
print(myString)
```